# Screen blanks at login screen

Tags: linux-mint, power-management, screensaver

On Linux Mint 17.1, the screen blanks when left idle.  To stop this from happening, I have checked all the obvious candidates on the Power Settings and Login Window screens.

[image: Power management setting screenshot]

[image: Screen locker settings screenshot]

Can anyone help me figure out how to stop the screen from going black at an idle login prompt?

Comment: By "idle login prompt", do you mean a text mode console login, or a Display Manager login window?

Comment: @Majenko, I meant display manager login window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check screensaver. Normally it's set for a minute on new installs.

Comment: It's been years since I was near that computer (or even that distro version), but given you're the only one to try to help have some rep :-)